# PHP variable like $var['$var']

Tags: php, var

I'm current making a website with a photo album in it. The website in 2 languages, english and dutch. So I made language file like:

```
$lang['hello'] = 'Hallo'; //Hallo is hello in dutch
```

With the photo album I'm trying use the same principle like:

```
$lang['discription_001'] = 'photo of a house';
```

With showing the images I made a counter, now I want to use the same counter in the dispription like so:

```
echo $lang['discription_'$counter]
```

And `$counter` being `001` for photo number one. However this does not work, Could someone tell how I could get this to work, or any other method to get what I want.

Thanks in advance, Thomas de Zeeuw

P.S. I'm new in PHP, however I normally pick up things quite fast, so make some explaintion would be appreciated.

Comment: echo $lang['discription_' . $counter];

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there:

```
echo $lang['discription_' . $counter]
```

The `.` is PHP's concatenation operator, for combining strings.

Comment: I got it to work now, still not sure what I did wrong before, but Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

You just forgot the [string concatenation operator `.`](http://php.net/language.operators.string) to concatenate `'discription_'` and the value of `$counter`:

```
$lang['discription_'.$counter]
```

Comment: I did forget the . , thank you for that. However now I get: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ']' as error. And thanks for the very fast response

Comment: @Thomas de Zeeuw: Then the cause of this error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo.

```
echo $lang['discription_'$counter]
```

Should be

```
echo $lang['discription_' . $counter];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get it to work by simple repairing your code:

```
echo $lang['discription_'.$counter];
```

or

```
echo $lang["discription_{$counter}"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `$counter` a string?? If so your example should work fine if you fix the parse error (You missed the concatenation operator (`.`).

It would be much better if you showed us actual code from your application.

`echo $lang['discription_' . $counter];`

Answer (score 0):

As you have got answers already you forgot the concatenation operator, but better way in my mind would be to use multidimensional array.

```
echo $lang['descriptions'][$counter];
```